# Fraud Detection model using Scikit Learn Python Library

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn

I'm new to machine learning world and currently in learning stage as a beginner. I have built and trained a model for fraud detection for a dataset of transactions held on a store.

Here's the complete code of my model:

```
df_full = pd.read_excel('input/invoiced_products_noinvoiceids_inproduct_v2.0.xlsx', sheet_name=0,)
df_full = df_full[df_full.filter(regex='^(?!Unnamed)').columns]
df_full.drop(['paymentdetails',], 1, inplace=True)
df_full.drop(['timestamp'], 1, inplace=True)
# Handle non numaric data
def handle_non_numaric_data(df_full):
    columns = df_full.columns.values

    for column in columns:
        text_digit_vals = {}
        def convert_to_int(val):
            return text_digit_vals[val]

        if df_full[column].dtype != np.int64 and df_full[column].dtype != np.float64:
            column_contents = df_full[column].values.tolist()
            unique_elements = set(column_contents)
            x = 0
            for unique in unique_elements:
                if unique not in text_digit_vals:
                    text_digit_vals[unique] = x
                    x+=1

            df_full[column] = list(map(convert_to_int, df_full[column]))

    return df_full

   df_full = handle_non_numaric_data(df_full)
   print(df_full.head())

   #for convert to numeric
   df_full['discount'] = pd.to_numeric(df_full['discount'], errors='coerce')
   df_full['productdiscount'] = pd.to_numeric(df_full['discount'], errors='coerce')
    df_full['Class'] = ((df_full['discount'] &gt; 20) &amp; 
                        (df_full['tax'] == 0) &amp;
                        (df_full['productdiscount'] &gt; 20) &amp;
                        (df_full['total'] &gt; 100)).astype(int)
    # print (df_full)
    df_full.to_csv('InvoiceData.csv')


# Get some sample data from entire dataset
data = df_full.sample(frac = 0.5, random_state = 1)

 print(data.shape)
data.isnull().sum()
# Convert excel data into matrix
columns = "invoiceid locationid timestamp customerid discount tax total subtotal productid quantity productprice productdiscount invoice_products_id producttax invoice_payments_id paymentmethod paymentdetails amount Class(0/1) Class".split()
X = pd.DataFrame.as_matrix(data, columns=columns)
Y = data.Class
# temp = np.array(temp).reshape((len(temp), 1)
Y = Y.values.reshape(Y.shape[0], 1)
X.shape
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size = 0.06)
X_test, X_dev, Y_test, Y_dev = train_test_split(X_test, Y_test, test_size = .5)

# Check if there is Classification Values - 0/1 in training set and other set 
np.where(Y_train == 1)
np.where(Y_test == 1)
np.where(Y_dev == 1)

# Determine no of fraud cases in dataset
Fraud = data[data['Class'] == 1]
Valid = data[data['Class'] == 0]

# calculate percentages for Fraud &amp; Valid 
outlier_fraction = len(Fraud) / float(len(Valid))

print('Fraud Cases : {}'.format(len(Fraud)))
print('Valid Cases : {}'.format(len(Valid)))
print(outlier_fraction)

# Get all the columns from dataframe
columns = data.columns.tolist()

# Filter the columns to remove data we don't want

columns = [c for c in columns if c not in ["Class"] ]

# store the variables we want to predicting on
target = "Class"
# for column in data.columns:
#     if data[column].dtype == type(object):
#         le = LabelEncoder()
#         data[column] = le.fit_transform(data[column])
#         X = data[column]
# X = data[column]        
# Y = data[target]
X = data.drop(target, 1)
Y = data[target]

# Print the shapes of X &amp; Y
print(X.shape)
print(Y.shape) 

# define a random state
state = 1

# # define the outlier detection method
# clf = IsolationForest(
#     max_samples=20, random_state=state)

classifiers = {
    "Isolation Forest": IsolationForest(max_samples=len(X),
                                       contamination=outlier_fraction,
                                       random_state=state),
    "Local Outlier Factor": LocalOutlierFactor(
    n_neighbors = 20,
    contamination = outlier_fraction)
}

# fit the model
n_outliers = len(Fraud)

for i, (clf_name, clf) in enumerate(classifiers.items()):

    # fit te data and tag outliers
    if clf_name == "Local Outlier Factor":
        y_pred = clf.fit_predict(X)
        print("LOF executed")
        scores_pred = clf.negative_outlier_factor_
        # Export the classifier to a file
        with open('model.pkl', 'wb') as model_file:
            pickle.dump(clf, model_file)
    else:
        clf.fit(X)
        scores_pred = clf.decision_function(X)
        y_pred = clf.predict(X)
        print("IF executed")
        # Export the classifier to a file
        with open('model.pkl', 'wb') as model_file:
            pickle.dump(clf, model_file)
    # Reshape the prediction values to 0 for valid and 1 for fraudulent
    y_pred[y_pred == 1] = 0
    y_pred[y_pred == -1] = 1

    n_errors = (y_pred != Y).sum()


# run classification metrics 
print('{}:{}'.format(clf_name, n_errors))
print(accuracy_score(Y, y_pred ))
print(classification_report(Y, y_pred ))
```

> **And here is the final output of this model:**

```
Local Outlier Factor:115
0.9997806549072266
             precision    recall  f1-score   support

 0            1.00           1.00      1.00    524231
 1            0.00           0.00      0.00        57

avg / total   1.00           1.00      1.00    524288
```

After that, when I  try to get a prediction by using a flask service it returns `[1]` for both(Normal and Fraudulent) cases.

What I did wrong in this model?

What can I​ be improved?
Is there something wrong with my data?

Help me, please!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

According to the model summary, your dataset is **extremely imbalanced** - negative examples are ten thousand less likely than positive ones.

Your classifiers only learned to see the first class. Your model doesn't predict anything as second class.

If you want to overcome this, try undersampling or oversampling (I would start with training with only couple hundred positive examples and all negative examples).

I also suggest looking at other questions about imbalanced datasets (actually I think that is common for fraud detection, so there may exist solutions for that particular problem type).

Comment: Hi @Jakub, I have tried to make my dataset balanced with enough +ve and -ve records using SMOTE, but now it returns another error as: `ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32').` when I call the predict method. How can I solve this issue? Help me, please!

Comment: Don't use SMOTE. Just take all of the BAD's (class=1), and take a random sample of ~100 times as many GOOD's. Train your model on that dataset.